# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null will not recognize id in getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, getelementbyid

I have decided to work with Firebase instead of using SQL and PHP, which is making the backend development easier. However, I'm getting the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null error for the ID element: login_div.

Most of this code is from a YouTube video [Firebase web login tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKlWaUszxB4&list=LLZqBLNiWJzv-LMFxEuBzURA). The issue started when I attempted to move the log out button out of the index page and onto another HTML file. I decided to keep a copy on both, however, the whole page keeps constantly refreshing and going back and forth between login page and my homepage, if the line `document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";` is changed or removed and I don't know how to fix this. I tried changing the ID name which did nothing and tried moving the div into the homepage which just started refreshing the whole page over and over again.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  //checking with firebase if there is a user
  if (user) {

    // User is signed in successful
    //document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user !== null) {
      //what to display if user is logged in
      window.location.href = "chat.html";

    }

  } else {
    // No user logged in displays login div hides user div
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }

});

function login() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPassword = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
    // Error messages for failed login
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    window.alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
  });
}

function logout() {
  //log out function 
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- login in page and button -->
  <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h1>The Bridge Login</h1>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password_field" />
    <button onclick="login()">Log In</button>
  </div>

  <div id="user_div" class="loggedIn-div">
    <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>

  <!-- firebase authentication server connection-->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should hide most of config properties, for example, apiKey.

Comment: I love that the above comment comes from a user basically named "learn the hard way".

Comment: @Learnonhardway The config properties you point out are not secrets, but merely configuration data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public